# Dynamically construct the style attribute of a TextCtrl in wxPython

Tags: wxpython

In creating a text control, we typically construct a style attribute with one or more integers, separated with the OR (|) symbol:

```
control = wx.TextCtrl(self, id=wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.TE_PASSWORD | wx.TE_CENTER | wx.TE_READONLY)
```

I would like to add style values dynamically, based on conditions, after I instantiate the control, but before rendering in the window. something like that:

```
if attr in dict_passwords:
    control.addStyle(wx.TE_PASSWORD)
if attr in dict_readonly:
    control.addStyle(wx.TE_READONLY)
...
```

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 ways to achieve this.
You can preassign the attributes to variables or you can add them as you go.
PreAssign:

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Variable TextCtrl style attributes')
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        mystyle1 = wx.TE_READONLY
        mystyle2 = wx.TE_READONLY | wx.TE_CENTER
        mystyle3 = wx.TE_READONLY | wx.TE_PASSWORD
        mystyle4 = wx.TE_READONLY | wx.TE_CENTER | wx.TE_PASSWORD
        mystyle5 = wx.TE_PASSWORD
        tc0 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,value="Ctrl 0",pos=(10,10),size=(350,20))
        tc1 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,value="Ctrl 1",pos=(10,40),size=(350,20),style=mystyle1)
        tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,value="Ctrl 2",pos=(10,70),size=(350,20),style=mystyle2)
        tc3 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,value="Ctrl 3",pos=(10,100),size=(350,20),style=mystyle3)
        tc4 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,value="Ctrl 4",pos=(10,130),size=(350,20),style=mystyle4)
        tc5 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,value="Ctrl 5",pos=(10,160),size=(350,20),style=mystyle5)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Dynamic:

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Variable TextCtrl style attributes')
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        tc0 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,value="Ctrl 0",pos=(10,10),size=(350,20))
        tc1 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,value="Ctrl 1",pos=(10,40),size=(350,20))
        tc1.SetWindowStyleFlag(wx.TE_READONLY)
        tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,value="Ctrl 2",pos=(10,70),size=(350,20))
        tc2.SetWindowStyleFlag(wx.TE_READONLY | wx.TE_CENTER)
        tc3 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,value="Ctrl 3",pos=(10,100),size=(350,20))
        tc3.SetWindowStyleFlag(wx.TE_READONLY | wx.TE_RIGHT)
        tc4 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,value="Ctrl 4",pos=(10,130),size=(350,20))
        tc4.SetWindowStyleFlag(wx.TE_READONLY | wx.TE_CENTER | wx.PASSWORD)
        tc5 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,value="Ctrl 5",pos=(10,160),size=(350,20),style=wx.TE_PASSWORD)
        s = tc5.GetWindowStyleFlag()
        tc5.SetWindowStyleFlag(s+wx.TE_RIGHT)
        tc6 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,value="Ctrl 6",pos=(10,190),size=(350,20))
        s = tc6.GetWindowStyleFlag()
        tc6.SetWindowStyleFlag(s+wx.TE_RIGHT)
        s = tc6.GetWindowStyleFlag()
        tc6.SetWindowStyleFlag(s+wx.TE_PASSWORD)

        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rolf for the effort, but it seems my question was mis-understood. Your not suggesting dynamic BUILD of the style attribute, but rather pre-setting many controls with combinations of styles.

Comment: Look at how `tc6` is assigned its style attributes

Answer (score 0):

Posting here the solution I found for this, for anyone who needs it:
Instead of building the styles after the instantiation, I build it now before-hand, using a function I wrote for this

```
def getControlStyle(attr):
    myStyle = 0
    if attr in globalvariables.list_olv_readonly:
        myStyle = myStyle | wx.TE_READONLY
    if attr in globalvariables.list_olv_multiline:
        myStyle = myStyle | wx.TE_MULTILINE
    if attr in globalvariables.list_olv_password:
        myStyle = myStyle | wx.TE_PASSWORD
    if attr in globalvariables.list_olv_aligncenter:
        myStyle = myStyle | wx.TE_CENTER
    if attr in globalvariables.list_olv_alignright:
        myStyle = myStyle | wx.TE_RIGHT
    return myStyle
```

Now, I instantiate the control as follows:

```
controlStyle = getControlStyle(attr)
...
self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, id=olv_dict[attr][1], value=str(attrDefaultValue), style=controlStyle)
```

Comment: This looks suspiciously like the ideas expressed in my answer, which you have simply put into a function.

Comment: Rolf. Yes, just now I see your tc5 and tc6 are accumulating styles. The lengthy start assigning combinations of styles confused me. Well, now there are two ways of doing that here for everyone to benefit.... Thanks!

Comment: The "lengthy start"? The point to an answer that attempts to show multiple ways to achieve something, is to start simply and then move on to the more complicated. It doesn't have a lengthy start, middle or end, it is intended to be a whole and should be read as such.

Comment: Hi Rolf. By "lengthy start" I meant in both ways you present, the first assignments are not addressing the question, thus gives the impression that you are offering an answer to another question. Only when you get to tc5, tc6, it shows that it is a possible solution to the question. Anyways, I trust all solutions presented here will benefit whomever needs either solution in the future and I thank you for your contribution!